# Coursera Python final project sentiment classifier

Tags: python, twitter

Finally, copy in your previous functions and write code that opens the file project_twitter_data.csv which has the fake generated twitter data (the text of a tweet, the number of retweets of that tweet, and the number of replies to that tweet). Your task is to build a sentiment classifier, which will detect how positive or negative each tweet is. Copy the code from the code windows above, and put that in the top of this code window. Now, you will write code to create a CSV file called resulting_data.csv, which contains the Number of Retweets, Number of Replies, Positive Score (which is how many happy words are in the tweet), Negative Score (which is how many angry words are in the tweet), and the Net Score (how positive or negative the text is overall) for each tweet. The file should have those headers in that order. Remember that there is another component to this project. You will upload the CSV file to Excel or Google Sheets and produce a graph of the Net Score vs Number of Retweets. Check Coursera for that portion of the assignment, if you’re accessing this textbook from Coursera.

Need Help with this question. Have been stuck on this one since about 1 week. please help this is the final project.

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(a):
    for x in punctuation_chars:
        if x in a:
            a = a.replace(x,"")
    return(a)
positive_words = []
with open("positive_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            positive_words.append(lin.strip())
def get_pos(c):
    pos = 0
    b = c.lower()
    b = strip_punctuation(b)
    lst = b.split(" ")
    for i in positive_words:
        for j in lst:
            if i == j:
                pos+=1
    return pos
negative_words = []
with open("negative_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            negative_words.append(lin.strip())
def get_neg(c):
    neg = 0
    b = c.lower()
    b = strip_punctuation(b)
    lst = b.split(" ")
    for i in negative_words:
        for j in lst:
            if i == j:
                neg+=1
    return neg
file = open("project_twitter_data.csv", "r")
e = file.read()
nega = posi = 0
for f in e:
    nega += get_neg(f)
    negat = nega*-1
    posi += get_pos(f)
negat = nega*-1
ne = str(nega)
po = str(posi)
net = posi + negat
netd = str(net)
filer = open('resulting_data.csv','w')
result = filer.write('Number of Retweets, Number of Replies, Positive Score, Negtive Score, Net Score\n')
result = filer.write('0, 0, ' + ne +', ' + po +", " + netd + '\n')
```

This is all I could think off. I cant use import CSV in this. It is not allowing me to.

some good words -

```html
a+
abound
abounds
abundance
abundant
accessable
accessible
acclaim
acclaimed
acclamation
```

these words are stored in the file positive_words.txt
some negative words -

```html
2-faced
2-faces
abnormal
abolish
abominable
abominably
abominate
abomination
abort
```

these words are stored in negative_words.txt
Twitter data -

```html
tweet_text,retweet_count,reply_count
@twitteruser: On now - @Fusion scores first points #FirstFinals @overwatchleague @umich @umsi Michigan Athletics made out of emojis. #GoBlue,3,0
BUNCH of things about crisis respons… available July 8th… scholarship focuses on improving me… in North America! A s… and frigid temperatures,1,0
FREE ice cream with these local area deals: chance to
```

Also after this I have to save it in a file that is in CSV format

Comment: If you want help, you need to put a bit more effort into making it easy for others to want to help you. For instance, what's in the `project_twitter_data.csv`? Can you share maybe the first few lines of it? Also, you say you are stuck - how so? Where are you stuck? Why don't you talk a bit about what you've written so far, and why you've written it that way? Also, you said "I can't use `import csv` in this. It's not allowing me to." What isn't allowing you to? Is there an error? Be more specific. Help us help you.

Comment: ohk Thank Paul M.

Comment: in the Project_twitter_data.csv there is twitter data of post and retweets comments etc. we need to find out total num of positive words, negative posts and net total of them.

Comment: Also in the quesstion it syas that i cant use import csv method.

Comment: the positive words and negative words are provided before hand in 2 other different files.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any chance you can share the first few lines of the csv? Simply edit your original post and copy-and-paste them.

Comment: and also i have to remove the punctuation marks.

Comment: i have done the punctuation marks one in a function. and also i have done the counting of the words on a string variable. i just cant do it in a .csv file.

Comment: Ah, maybe you can also share some of the contents of the good and bad word files. Also, instead of a trail of comments, you can simply edit your original post with more information.

Comment: Please don't post so many comments. Just edit your original question with the new information please. You should also update your original post with the contents of the files - if you just paste the contents here, the formatting is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating your question. I'd start by defining an entry-point to your program, such as `main`. Then, just get the preliminary CSV (extremely naive) parsing to work. This just prints information about each entry in the CSV to verify we are parsing it correctly:

```
def main():

    with open("project_twitter_data.csv", "r") as file:
        # Skip the first line
        next(file)
        for tweet, retweet_count, reply_count in map(lambda line: line.strip().split(","), file):
            print(f"tweet: {tweet[:20]}...\nretweet_count: {retweet_count}\nreply_count: {reply_count}\n")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
tweet: @twitteruser: On now...
retweet_count: 3
reply_count: 0

tweet: BUNCH of things abou...
retweet_count: 1
reply_count: 0

>>>
```

My CSV file only has two entries in it, but it should work for any number of entries (as long as there are no commas in any of the tweets).

Then, you need to load your positive and negative words. I'm assuming the files aren't too large, so you should be OK reading all the words into lists. There are many different ways in which you could count the positive and negative words for each tweet. For example, you could split the current tweet on whitespace to get a list of "words". I say "words" because technically, these would be strings which could contain punctuation, so you would have to take that into account in some way. Another way would be to use a regular expression pattern with word boundraries to generate a list of words from the current tweet. The way I've done it below is just by looking for a substring in the current tweet, which is a bit naive. Unless there is a unittest in place that deliberately looks to make sure aren't using this approach, this should be good enough.

```
def main():

    with open("positive_words.txt", "r") as file:
        positive_words = file.read().splitlines()

    with open("negative_words.txt", "r") as file:
        negative_words = file.read().splitlines()

    with open("project_twitter_data.csv", "r") as file:
        # Skip the first line
        next(file)
        for tweet, retweet_count, reply_count in map(lambda line: line.strip().split(","), file):
            positive_count = sum(tweet.count(word) for word in positive_words)
            negative_count = sum(tweet.count(word) for word in negative_words)
            net_count = positive_count - negative_count
            # Write retweet_count, reply_count, positive_count, negative_count and net_count to resulting_data.csv
            
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, it worked for the coursera project, by MAB

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']

def strip_punctuation  (x):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        x = x.replace(i, '')
    return x
def get_pos (x):
    x = strip_punctuation(x)
    y = x.lower().split()
    count = 0
    for i in y:
        if i in positive_words:
            count = count + 1
    return count
def get_neg (x):
    x = strip_punctuation(x)
    y = x.lower().split()
    count = 0
    for i in y:
        if i in negative_words:
            count = count + 1
    return count

positive_words = []
with open("positive_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            positive_words.append(lin.strip())
negative_words = []
with open("negative_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            negative_words.append(lin.strip())

outfile = open("resulting_data.csv", "w")
outfile.write('Number of Retweets, Number of Replies, Positive Score, Negative Score, Net Score')
outfile.write('\n')

myfile = open('project_twitter_data.csv', 'r')
rows = myfile.readlines()[1:]
for line in rows:
    words = line.split()
    numbers = words[-1]
    twrt = numbers.split(',')
    print ('retweets: ', twrt[1], 'replies: ', twrt[2])
    pos_sco = 0
    neg_sco = 0
    for word in words:
        if word in positive_words:
            pos_sco = pos_sco + 1
        if word in negative_words:
            neg_sco = neg_sco + 1
    net_sco = pos_sco - neg_sco
    print ('positive words: ', pos_sco, 'negative words: ', neg_sco, 'Net score: ', net_sco )
    row_string = '{}, {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(twrt[1], twrt[2], pos_sco, neg_sco, net_sco)
    outfile.write(row_string)
    outfile.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here's an easy solution for that

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
    def strip_punctuation(word):
       for ch in punctuation_chars:
            word=word.replace(ch,"").lower()
    return word
positive_words = []
with open("positive_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            positive_words.append(lin.strip())
def get_pos(sentence):
    sent_lst = sentence.split(" ")
    new_lst_sent = []
    for word in sent_lst:
        word = strip_punctuation(word).lower()
        new_lst_sent.append(word)
    pos_count = 0
    for word in positive_words:
        if word in new_lst_sent:
            pos_count = pos_count + 1

negative_words = []
with open("negative_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            negative_words.append(lin.strip())
def get_neg(sentence):
    sent_lst = sentence.split(" ")
    new_lst_sent = []
    for word in sent_lst:
        word = strip_punctuation(word).lower()
        new_lst_sent.append(word)
    neg_count = 0
    for word in negative_words:
        if word in new_lst_sent:
            neg_count = neg_count + 1
    return neg_count

outfile = open("resulting_data.csv", "w")
outfile.write('Number of Retweets, Number of Replies, Positive Score,      Negative Score, Net Score')
outfile.write('\n')

myfile = open('project_twitter_data.csv', 'r')
rows = myfile.readlines()[1:]
for line in rows:
    words = line.split()
    numbers = words[-1]
    twrt = numbers.split(',')
    print ('retweets: ', twrt[1], 'replies: ', twrt[2])
    pos_sco = 0
    neg_sco = 0
    for word in words:
        if word in positive_words:
            pos_sco = pos_sco + 1
        if word in negative_words:
            neg_sco = neg_sco + 1
    net_sco = pos_sco - neg_sco
    print ('positive words: ', pos_sco, 'negative words: ', neg_sco, 'Net score: ', net_sco )
    row_string = '{}, {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(twrt[1], twrt[2], pos_sco, neg_sco, net_sco)
    outfile.write(row_string)
    outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me ..

punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(word):
    New_word=""  
    for w in word:
        if w not in punctuation_chars:
            New_word=New_word+w
    return New_word
positive_words = []
with open("positive_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            positive_words.append(lin.strip())
negative_words = []
with open("negative_words.txt") as pos_f:
    for lin in pos_f:
        if lin[0] != ';' and lin[0] != '\n':
            negative_words.append(lin.strip())           
def get_neg(word):      #Gives you the negative score
    count = 0
    word = strip_punctuation(word)
    word = word.lower().split()
    for item in word:
        if item in negative_words:
            count = count+1
    return count            
def get_pos(s):      #Gives you the positive score
    count = 0
    s= strip_punctuation(s)
    s = s.lower().split()
    #print(s)
    for item in s:
        if item in positive_words:
            count = count+1
    return count
outfile = open("resulting_data.csv","w")
outfile.write("Number of Retweets, Number of Replies, Positive Score, Negative Score, Net Score")
outfile.write("\n")
fileref = open("project_twitter_data.csv","r")
lines = fileref.readlines()[1:]
for line in lines:
    positive_score = get_pos(line) #using our pre-defined function
    negative_score = get_neg(line)
    net_score = positive_score - negative_score
    my_line = line.split(",")
    #print(my_line)
    retweets = int(my_line[1])
    n_reply = int(my_line[2])
    file_line = "{},{},{},{},{}".format(retweets, n_reply, positive_score, negative_score, net_score)
    outfile.write(file_line)
    outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.